# Applying accurate colors from desktop screen to Mobile applications

Tags: color

I am currently working on some skin designs for an android application and
in order to achieve the desired color results, I did some color test to it.

I save my files in .png and .jpg versions and open it up in my mobile only to
realize that the colors appear much brighter(neon like colors) than my original display.

I tried to desaturate it and well the colors seem better but the colors on
my desktop screen shows purple while on my mobile it shows pink.

I tried several color schemers and realize the intended colors do not display
correctly from desktop screens to mobile screens.

I tested it on iphone and the colors render exactly the same I intended it to be,
whereas the android phone (HTC Desire, Motorola ) is way to bright for the eyes to even read.

I am currently working on a pink color skin.Is it due to the display of mobile devices? OR is there a way to choose specific colors for mobile applications and ensure that it renders the same for all mobile devices?

Comment: Colours on my Nexus 7 are always very different to colours on my Galaxy S3 - they are both android but use different screen technologies. Food for thought.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to choose specific colors for mobile applications and ensure that it renders the same for all mobile devices?

Sorry to disappoint you, but: no, definitely not. There are too many parameters *heavily* influencing the result. Most important: screen technology and lighting/viewing conditions – both of which vary over a nearly infinite range. Especially considering the lighting, any kind of color calibration is doomed to fail (calibration only works for clearly defined viewing conditions).

Your best bet might be to design using *sRGB* as your color profile and to chose key colors directly on the most important devices themselves.

Comment: Yes I used sRGB as well

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a problem with your monitor calibration.
I'm not sure there is a color-profile that maintain consistency from Android to PC/MAC.
BTW are you using a mac or a pc? Color profiles are very different on each other.
I worked with a mac and created design for Android devices, and although the color was not exactly the same the results was okay. I didn't have any "neon-style" effects or over-saturate colors.

Comment: Unfortunately, calibration won't help much (see my own answer).

Comment: I am on a PC and yup, I did several calibrations to my computer but it doesn't make any difference or perhaps MAC does makes a bigger difference in terms of color? 

I tried a few handsets such as blackberry as well, and it turns out pretty close like the iphone, except android phones or should I say, HTC? For the current HTC phone I am using,
the color display appears vibrant even with the phone colors setting calibrated as well.Certain hues such as green, yellow, red can be glaring at times causing eyes to strain when viewed 

I think perhaps I will start testing out on a MAC next.Thanks!